# How to get data according to days from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

```
var data = [{

  "_id": "56966b68ffcd653c237",
  "created_at": "2016-01-13T15:21:12.376Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-01-13T15:21:12.376Z",
  "topic": "5681b1df54521e2c1442",
  "56854031187bf9780ed05111": "Name",
  "56854109187bf9780ed05115": 20,
  "56966b2effcd653c2374a9da": {
     "title": "No Pain"
  },
  "__v": 0
},

{.....},

{
.....}]
```

This is my object.
I want to write function getLastData(noOfDays) in angular which return data according to last no of days.
suppose noOfDays= 3; It give me all data updated on last 3 days.

If possible i want sorted according to time stamp.

Comment: We appreciate that you've let us to know, that you "want to write function". But what is your question?

Comment: I want to get data accroding to days. suppose noOfdays is 3,I want all data of last 3 days. User can add thier data everyday .now if they want to see data from last 5 days then noOfdays = 5. now to to get last 5 dyas data from this object.

Comment: also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I thought _you_ want to write a function, but now it appears, that you want _us_ to write a function. That's off-topic for SO, please try something first, and if you get stuck, then ask a question. If you already have some code, please add it to your post, and explain what troubles you're having with it.

Comment: var data has all data from database.How to filter it based on "created_at" ?

Comment: I am new to angular and don't have idea how to do it.I tried splice but it didn't work with time. at least if I get an idea I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$scope.filteredData = [];

$scope.getLastData = function(noOfDays) {

var 3rddayTime = // find out

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data.updated_at > 3rddayTime) {
    $scope.filteredData.push(data[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Suppose if you want to display last 3 days data on UI, to achieve this you should use ng-repeat with ng-if

```
<div ng-repeate="d in data">
    <p ng-if="d.updated_at > 3rd day time"></p>
</div>
```

you should have 3rd day time as a $scope variable in your controller